# give hostname to ansible hostname

Tags: ansible

this is all I have in a module

```
- debug: 
    msg: "apt update {{ item.hostname }}"
```

and it work's in the way that a list is looped and hostnames are showen.
Would it be possible to set ansible_hostname with item.hostname and run this

```
- name: Upgrade installed packages
  become: true
  apt:
    upgrade: dist
```

Comment: `ansible_hostname` is the discovered host name. It makes no sense to hack that variable in any way. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @cavin I misunderstood that sorry.Thanks explaininng it. LXOP had a nice solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I think you want to know if you can apply that second block to a host that has come from a variable. In that case, yes you can, just use `delegate_to`:

```
- name: Upgrade installed packages
  become: true
  apt:
    upgrade: dist
  delegate_to: "{{ item.hostname }}"
  connection: ssh  # You may or may not need this line
```

The last line (`connection: ssh`) is necessary if you are using a recent version of ansible and your play is set up with `connection: local`. I think it's possible that you might have that since you are not running this against a regular inventory based on the premise of your question.

Comment: thanks for that. didn't know about delegate and connection. You sensed right and works great